# How to fix an error while using command 'import cv2' in Python

Tags: python-3.x

Actually I have installed and downloaded Anaconda in my laptop. I am supposed to do a project on Face Recognition using OpenCV. I have downloaded and installed OpenCV in my laptop, but whenever I give 'import cv2' command in Jupyter Notebook or in Spyder, it throws a "ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes" error. What shall I do?
How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you install it using the pip command?

Comment: yes, i did that